# Show Image from URL in detailView after selection in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, segue, detailview

I have a tableView which display a list of traffic-cameras parsed from a XML file. When I select a cell, it sends the ImageURL, Roadname, Coordinates etc. via the prepareForSegue method.

In my detailviewcontroller I declare the incoming values as the following:

```
var selectedFeedURL = String()
var selectedFeedRoadname = String()
var selectedFeedLongitude = String()
var selectedFeedLatitude = String()
```

I have no problem printing all the values into the log or set it as labels. The problem occurs when I try to load the selectedFeedURL (which is the URL to the image, i.e: http://webkamera.vegvesen.no/kamera?id=559847) and set it to my imageView..

In my viewDidLoad, I have the following code, which should download the image and set it to my imageView named `cameraImageView`.

```
if let url = NSURL(string:"\(selectedFeedURL)") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
        print("Suksess")
        cameraImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }   
}
```

My imageView stays empty and I doesn't get any errors or complains in the debug area. If I print out the selectedFeedURL, the link is there.

The weird part is that if I change

```
NSURL(string:"\(selectedFeedURL)")
```

to

```
NSURL(string:"http://webkamera.vegvesen.no/kamera?id=559847")
```

Basically changing the variable to a camera URL, it works perfectly.

Soo... any suggestions on what the problem might be?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: This isn't your problem, but there is no need to do string interpolation on a `String`.  `NSURL(string: selectedFeedURL)` should be sufficient.

Comment: Print the value of selectedFeedURL.  Could it have non-printable characters in it?

Comment: Even spaces before or after your URL string could foul this up.  do `print("***\(selectedFeedURL)***")` and see if there are spaces before or after the URL in your variable.

Comment: @vacawama Okay, this is copied straight out of the debug area:

***http://webkamera.vegvesen.no/kamera?id=113094
    ***

It creates a linebreak and a lot of spaces, weird. Mkay, the linebreak doesn't show up in the comment section, nor does all the spaces. (its 5 spaces in total)

Comment: Try my answer.  It trims the whitespace and adds the needed `"http://"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are white spaces and newline characters at the start and end of your URL string, it won't work.

Try:

```
selectedFeedURL = selectedFeedURL.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

if let url = NSURL(string: selectedFeedURL) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
        print("Suksess")
        cameraImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Success! Although, I had to remove the "http://" code to make it work, it created a double http tag :) Thanks again ^_^

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll update my answer to reflect your comment.